# Accessing source files from JAR files

Tags: java, file-io, jar

I have a small question about accessing the resources from a JAR file. I have created a java class library using Netbeans IDE named processor. It has a package called `proc` which in turn has text file called `toRead.txt`. And now I have another java application which has class like `Main.java` which uses the processor library.

To obtain an `InputStream` to the text file I used the following code

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("proc/toRead.txt");
```

in Main.java.

Now I want to do it the other way around. I want to obtain an `InputStream` to `Main.java` in processor library. I tried the same code shown above , but it doesn't work.

How can we obtain `InputStream` on the Source itself in this library?

Comment: the same way as you done for toRead.txt , u need to pack .java aswell in the jar.

Comment: Does your jar contain source code?

Comment: *"I want to obtain an InputStream to `Main.java`"*  ***Why?***  And why is the source in the Jar?  Do you actually mean `Main.class`?  This question is very unclear.

Comment: @MayankSharma JAR contains an annotation processor which i have written and the Main.java is the annotated class. I am trying to read the annotated class(that is Main.java) by trying to open an InputStream from the processor within JAR.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you run the application or bundle it in a JAR, the Main.java file doesn't exist anymore. This must be because most IDEs compile the classes in a folder separate from the source code folder. Note that the Java compiler does preserve other resources, including TXT and GIF files, which is why the program allows you to read the text file when you run it.

As @TechExcahnge mentioned, if you **really** need to read the Main.java file, you'll need to manually package it in a JAR, which can be done with any program that supports the ZIP format.

Answer (score 0):

`SystemClassLoader` will not load you own class, `application classloader` or `user classloader` mybe load you own class.

Try this code:

```
 public class TestRead{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        InputStream is = TestRead.class.getResourceAsStream("proc/toRead.txt");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that jar file containing the resource is in the ClassPath.

Try this:

```
public InputStream getResourceUnderJarAsStream(){
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
return inputStream;
}
```